# Skip permutation elements in C++

Tags: c++

Here's my problem. I want to generate complete permutations from a 20 element array. But within the permutation process I want to be able to use conditionals to test various attributes of each generated permutation and based on the outcome of the tests, discontinue or skip over an entire block and then continue generating permutations.

For example: Using just a,b,c,d as the elements of the array, a full permutation set would produce:

```
abcd
abdc
acbd
acdb
adbc
adcb
bacd
badc
bcad
bcda
bdac
bdca
cabd
cadb
cbad
cbda
cdab
cdba
dabc
dacb
dbac
dbca
dcab
dcba
```

But let's say that after testing during execution of the permutation loop, it's decided that any new permutation beginning with 'b' will be invalid, so I want to skip all of those and continue with permutations beginning with 'c'. I want this skipping to be able to be carried out on any letter at any place within the set, let's say that on arriving at 'cabd' it's decided to skip all future permutations beginning with 'ca' and move on immediately to 'cbad'. Is this possible? Can someone steer me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: You should try it using recursion. That way you shall have more control on whether you want to permute an arrangement further or skip it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a wrapper method over `std::next_permutation` that calls it internally until some condition is met and then returns.

```
template <class BidirectionalIterator>
void my_next_permutation (BidirectionalIterator first,
                     BidirectionalIterator last);
{
    do
    {
        next_permutation(first, last);
    } while ( !MyCondition(first, last) );
    //MyCondition can also be passed by parameter
}
```